# Trying to create a search/copy/paste VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, reporting

I am new to VBA and I'm trying to automate a reporting function on a spreadsheet which requires manual work that could be avoided. I have created the below code but I keep on receiving error messages. I will explain what I am trying to achieve and hopefully we will find a solution to this issue.

I have two sheets, and I want to look into column L of Sheet1 and for all cells that has "NO" for value, I want to copy the value in column A of the same row, and paste it in the last row of Sheet2 in the column A.

Sounds pretty simple but I cannot get my head around the code.

What is wrong with the below code?

```
    Sub SearchMacro()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    wb.Activate
    ws.Select

RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To RowCount
    Range("L" & i).Select
    If ActiveCell = "NO" Then
        ActiveCell.Range("A").Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A" & RowCount + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the error messages you are seeing?

Comment: Sorry - I get "runtime error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"...

Comment: You are using RowCount on both sheet1 and sheet2. That works in Excel VBA, but not on all other programming languages. The reason it works here is because the loop is set and can't be changed, thus the variable can be changed. But I advice you not to use this method as it is confusing and odd to say the least. Where do you get the error?

Comment: Have you even looked at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use autofilter instead of looping.

```
RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Cells.AutoFilter ' set an filter on the sheet
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:L" & RowCount) ' filter on NO column L
    .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="NO"
End With
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:L" & Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy 'Copy the filtered data
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & RowCount + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Just reviewed your response - I get an error at the AutoFilter stage.. method of Range class failed?

Comment: Which line. There are two lines with autofilter. I see in the other comments your sheets are not named sheet1 and 2. What size is the table? A:L? Or is it larger?

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of tempted to flag this question as duplicate, because there's tons of these copy-paste data questions on daily basis, but oh well..

1. **Don't use `Select/ActiveCell/Activesheet/Activeworkbook/..` period!!** It's a bad `vba-excel` practice that can always be avoided. Also, Just because your loop through RowCount doesn't mean the cell is active. This is probably also the reason why you keep getting errors: `Application.ActiveCell` under MSDN definition is as follows:

   > **Returns a Range object that represents the active cell in the active
   >   window** (the window on top) or in the specified window. **If the window
   >   isn't displaying a worksheet, this property fails**. Read-only.

   *(for more info on how to avoid using these refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) stackoverflow question)*
2. There are some small errors in your code altogether. I don't have the data you are working with, nor info on which sheet is which, so I'll just go with presumption Sheet1 contains data you want to copy and Sheet2 where you want to paste it

   ```
   Private Sub copy_paste()

   Dim ws_source As Worksheet: Set ws_source = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Dim ws_target As Worksheet: Set ws_target = Sheets("Sheet2")

   Dim last_row As Long
   last_row = ws_source.Cells(ws_source.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
   Dim next_paste As Long

   For i = 1 To last_row
       If ws_source.Cells(i, "L") = "NO" Then
           ws_source.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
           next_paste = ws_target.Cells(ws_target.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
           ws_target.Rows(next_paste).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       End If
   Next i

   End Sub
   ```

With data:
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

Comment: `ws_target.Rows(i).Paste` i believe OP want's to paste on first empty row of sheet2. Your code just make line5 = line5. But if you run this two times I believe it should append. If I understood the question corrrect.

Comment: @Andreas Apologies, I misread, OP's question (thought it said to be pasted on where the row was found). Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hey - thanks both for your prompt response. Now I get Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed... 

The error seems to be on the line starting with last_row = ws...

Comment: @Themedster I presume that's because your sheets are named differently (eg. ws_source is not called Sheet1 in your   document) I guess adding a dot infront of cells in both next_paste and last_row wouldn't hur either... eg. `ws_source.Range(.Cells(....` I was not using proper syntax out of lazyness.

Comment: I did edit the sheets name before  running the Macro, I will try to review the syntax and see how it works...

Comment: @Themedster Hi, apologies. Actually there was an error on my part... I edited my answer (code). For some reason I decided to refer to empty range instead of the individual cells in the last row.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FIND`.  This will find *NO* but not *No* or *nO* (change to `MatchCase=False` to find all cases).

```
Public Sub SearchAndCopy()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAdd As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'ActiveWorkbook
                          'Workbooks("SomeWorkbook.xlsx")
                          'Workbooks.Open("SomePath/SomeWorkbook.xlsx")

    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With ws.Columns("L")
        Set rFound = .Find(What:="NO", _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                           MatchCase:=True)

        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAdd = rFound.Address
            Do
                'Find next empty row on destination sheet.
                    'Only really need to give worksheet reference when
                    'counting rows if you have 2003 & 2007+ files open - "ws.Rows.Count"
                last_row = ws1.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                'Copy the figure from source to target sheet.
                'You could also use Copy/Paste if you want the formatting as well.
                ws1.Cells(last_row, 1) = ws.Cells(rFound.Row, 1)

                'Look for the next matching value in column L.
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirstAdd
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

I've added an explanation of your code below - the main thing wrong with your code is `ActiveCell.Range("A").Copy`.  There is no range `A`, but there is `A1`,`A2`, etc.

```
Sub SearchMacro()

    'You didn't declare these two which
    'indicates you haven't got Option Explicit
    'at the top of your module.
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'I'll only comment that you set
    'wb to be the ActiveWorkbook and you then
    'activate the active workbook which is already active.....
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    wb.Activate
    ws.Select

    'Looks at the active sheet as you just activated it.
    'Generally better to say "the cells in this named worksheet, even if it isn't active, or
    'in the active book... just reference the damn thing."
    'Something like "ws.cells(ws.cells.rows.count,"A").End(xlUp).Row"
    'Note it references the correct worksheet each time.
    RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To RowCount
        Range("L" & i).Select
        If ActiveCell = "NO" Then

            'Your code falls over here - you can't have range A.
            'You can have range A1, which is the first cell in your referenced range.
            'So ActiveCell.Range("A1") will return the ActiveCell - "L1" probably.
            ActiveCell.Range("A1").Copy

            'This will copy from column A using your method:
            'ws.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Copy

            'If you get the above line correct this will all work.
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("A" & RowCount + 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'You've already called it "ws" so just "ws.Select" will work.
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are going to refactor/repair the code then remove `Select`, `ActiveCell` etc. Don't encourage bad coding practices!

Comment: @AJD My first bit of code doesn't use `Select`or `ActiveCell`. The second is just a copy of the original code with added comments.